# Как отловить события сворачивания и разворачивания NavigationView?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Можно ли как-то отловить события сворачивания/разворачивания "шторки" `NavigationView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть слушатель событий:

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
   this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
drawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View view) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });
```

надеюсь это то что вам нужно :)